# Cannot ping remote host across GRE tunnel over IPSec

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, vpn, tunnel, ipsec

I need to setup a GRE tunnel over IPSec to support multicast and, at the same time, encrypt my communication.

I managed to setup the IPSec tunnel (strongswan) in EC2. I can ping the remote host and I verified everything is working OK.

I tried to configure GRE over the IPSec tunnel and, although the interface is UP and the configuration looks OK, I cannot reach the remote host.

I have edited my security group's inbound rules to allow GRE, AH & ESP protocols, UDP ports 4500 & 500, and ICMP protocol.

IPSec Tunnel

```
My IP: 10.0.0.1
Theirs: 10.0.0.2
```

GRE Tunnel

```
My IP: 10.244.251.210
Theirs: 10.244.251.209
Subnet: 10.244.251.208/30
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto tun0
iface tun0 inet static
address 10.244.251.210
netmask 255.255.255.252
pre-up ip tunnel add tun0 mode gre local 10.0.0.1 remote 10.0.0.2 ttl 255
up ip link set tun0 multicast on
up ip link set tun0 up
up ip addr add 10.244.251.210/30 dev tun0
```

ubuntu:~$ ip route

```
default via 172.10.0.1 dev eth0
10.244.251.208/30 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.244.251.210
```

ubuntu:~$ ip addr

```
5: tun0@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8977 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/gre 10.0.0.1 peer 10.0.0.2
    inet 10.244.251.210/30 brd 10.244.251.211 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5efe:af4:f68a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Do you see anything wrong or missing?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post it in Server Fault.